# Find files with string

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf, grep, mv

How can i grep e move pdf files that containing the string "RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES" inside? Using ubuntu 14.4.

I already try to use:

```
grep -i -Z -r -l 'RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES' . | xargs -I{} mv {} ./destination

grep -lir 'RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES' target/* | xargs mv -t destionation/

mv `grep -lir 'RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES' target` destination/
```

But none of this work, at all. No errors, no outputs, nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot check it at present, but if you can generate correctly the list (put attention to the spaces) then you can pipe to awk and create the command to move them. Mind the `""` before and after the full path and filename.

Comment: Your main problem is that text in PDF files is encoded, so will never be found by `grep`. @techraf's answer suggests using `pdfgrep`, but other filters are possible, such as using `lesspipe` or `pdftotext`.

Answer (score 3):

You should install `pdfgrep` package with:

```
sudo apt-get install pdfgrep
```

and run:

```
pdfgrep -Hc 'RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES' target/* | cut -d : -f1 | xargs -I{} mv -i '{}' ./destination
```

---

## Test first!

Replace `mv` with `echo mv`:

```
pdfgrep -Hc 'RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES' target/* | cut -d : -f1 | xargs -I{} echo mv -i '{}' ./destination
```

and see if you get correct `mv` commands with arguments.

---

Just for safety I suggest explicitly adding `-i` argument to `mv` so that it will demand confirmation if executing would result in overwriting an existing file.

Comment: I installed the pdfgrep. How could i use?

Comment: Done, just please always test and see before executing the real mv command.

Comment: `grep` will never find text content in PDF files, though it will find some of the PDF control strings, such as `job`/`endjob`, etc.

Comment: IUPI! It works!!!!!

Comment: Hei techraf, i was wrong, is not working :(.. i have 100 pdfs with this string inside and is moving 90% of the files.

Comment: I'm afraid if `pdfgrep` does not find the string there is not much you can do. Are all PDFs searchable ie. can you find the string using some reader search function (like Ctrl+f)?

Comment: Thats not the case at all i think @techraf cause when i try to use "pdfgrep -in 'RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES' PDF/*.pdf" will print the files with the string

Comment: No solution for that i'm guessing @techraf??

Comment: You didn't say if you can find the string in a pdf-reader.
There could be extra whitespace or newlines between the words.
If you shorten the searchphrase, is there any chance for false positives?